# Want to call multiple XMLHttpRequest based on how much data we have

Tags: javascript

So I have some Javascript that does an XMLHttpRequest (**xhr**), on receival of response it does a second response (**xhr2**) to get remaining data.

But I have now split this second call into batches so that it has to call multiple times depending on how much data there. After the first request I know how many calls I haven to make

```
var batches = Math.ceil((counter.innerText.substring(0,counter.innerText.indexOf(" ")) - 100) / 1000);
```

But then I am just making multiple calls to xdr2, but this doesn't work because it closes after first call. So I realize I probably need to initialize multiple *XMLHttpRequest*  based on the value of batches, but how do I define the *onreadystatechange* function succinctly.

```
function get_tracklist_data(path, cid, title)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
            var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
            counter.innerHTML = xhr.responseText.substring(0, xhr.responseText.indexOf(":"));

            var data    = document.getElementById("data");
            data.innerHTML = xhr.responseText.substring(xhr.responseText.indexOf(":") + 1);
    
            //Work out how many calls we need to make
            var batches = Math.ceil((counter.innerText.substring(0,counter.innerText.indexOf(" ")) - 100) / 1000);
            for(i=1; i<batches;i++)
            {
                xhr2.open('GET',path + '?cid=' + cid + "&title=" + title+"&batch=" + i, true);
                xhr2.send();
            }
        }
    };

    xhr2.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            {
                var data    = document.getElementById("tbody");
                data.innerHTML+=xhr2.responseText;
            }
        };
    xhr.open('GET',path + '?cid=' + cid + "&title=" + title +"&batch=0", true);
    xhr.send();
};
```

**Update** to make xhr2 local variable in loop, but doesnt seem to work properly Im getting the same data back multiple times.

```
function get_tracklist_data(path, cid, title)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
            var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
            counter.innerHTML = xhr.responseText.substring(0, xhr.responseText.indexOf(":"));

            var data    = document.getElementById("data");
            data.innerHTML = xhr.responseText.substring(xhr.responseText.indexOf(":") + 1);

            //Work out how many calls we need to make
            var batches = Math.ceil((counter.innerText.substring(0,counter.innerText.indexOf(" ")) - 100) / 1000);
            for(i=1; i<batches;i++)
            {
                var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr2.onreadystatechange = function()
                    {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                        {
                            var data    = document.getElementById("tbody");
                            data.innerHTML+=xhr2.responseText;
                        }
                    };
                xhr2.open('GET',path + '?cid=' + cid + "&title=" + title+"&batch=" + i, true);
                xhr2.send();
            }
        }
    };


    xhr.open('GET',path + '?cid=' + cid + "&title=" + title +"&batch=0", true);
    xhr.send();
};
```

Comment: Can you use axios or fetch? That should make things a bit easier

Comment: Unless you have to support IE7, there is really no point in the `onreadystatechange` game. Just do `.onload` or better yet - use `fetch` which is a more modern easier to use API. With async/await doing things like looping is triviial.

Comment: @DanielA.White hi, im not familiar with them, but Im sure it must be easy enough with vanilla javascript

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum im not familar with that, if it can be rewritten to use then fine, but Im thinking its going to add uneccesary new complications so a direct answer to the original question would be better for me.

Comment: @PaulTaylor that code looks like JavaScript written needing to support _very old_ browsers and it's also using very old JavaScript idioms/constructs. It can be made to work (you'd just call the retry/chunks in recursion) but it'd be much siimpler (a regular for loop) to do in JavaScript that isn't built to support IE7, a browser released in 2006 - when Bush was president of the US, iPhones didn't exist, this website didn't exist.. you get the point.

Comment: I think you only can use an xhr for a single request. otherwise it gets unruly.

Comment: Ive updated but not working, should it work. @BenjaminGruenbaum I accept your point but it doesnt really give a me a solution, my Javascript knowledge is limited so I am looking for a solution rather than just advice that what i have done is wrong.

Comment: problem with your for loop approach is your data is not guaranteed to come back in the correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here example using `await fetch()` and `fetch().then()`

```
function listenForButtonCollapse(buttonId, collapseId, buttonText) {
  let button = document.getElementById(buttonId);
  let section = document.getElementById(collapseId);
  if (section != null) {
    section.addEventListener('show.bs.collapse', function() {
      button.innerText = 'Hide ' + buttonText;
    });
    section.addEventListener('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
      button.innerText = 'Show ' + buttonText;
    });
  }
}

async function get_tracklist_data(path, cid, title) {
  let xhr = await fetch(path + '?cid=' + cid + "&title=" + title + "&batch=0");
  let responseText = await xhr.text()
  let counter = document.getElementById("counter");
  counter.innerHTML = responseText.substring(0, responseText.indexOf(":"));
  let data = document.getElementById("data");
  data.innerHTML = responseText.substring(responseText.indexOf(":") + 1);
  listenForButtonCollapse('show_focus_button', 'focus_id', 'Spotlight');
  listenForButtonCollapse('show_albums_button', 'albums_id', 'Albums');
  listenForButtonCollapse('show_tracks_button', 'tracks_id', 'Tracks');
  listenForButtonCollapse('show_works_button', 'works_id', 'Works');

  //Work out how many calls we need to make
  let batches = Math.ceil((counter.innerText.substring(0, counter.innerText.indexOf(" ")) - 100) / 1000);
  data = document.getElementById("tbody");
  for (i = 1; i < batches; i++) {
    fetch(path + '?cid=' + cid + "&title=" + title + "&batch=" + i)
      .then(resp => resp.text())
      .then(responseText => {
        data.innerHTML += responseText;
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Same as fetch, can he create second (or third or fourth) ```XMLHttpRequest``` object dynamically?

Comment: Problem with this approach is the output might be out of order.

Comment: @AmitKumar  yes he can, save the xhr object into array

Comment: @epascarello to return in order use `await fetch()` not `fetch().then()`

Comment: Just curious... What if event listener is ```bind``` with ```XMLHttpRequest object``` and ```this``` is used in event listener. Won't be any need to save in array, right?

Comment: @PaulTaylor I added answer using `XMLHttpRequest` see below and you are welcome

Comment: @AmitKumar replace `this` with `x.target` see my other answer

Answer (score 0):

Using XMLHttpRequest: save xhr object into array then add parameter to the callback `listXHR[i].onreadystatechange = function(x)` then call `x.target` for current xhr object

```
function get_tracklist_data(path, cid, title) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
      counter.innerHTML = xhr.responseText.substring(0, xhr.responseText.indexOf(":"));

      var data = document.getElementById("data");
      data.innerHTML = xhr.responseText.substring(xhr.responseText.indexOf(":") + 1);

      //Work out how many calls we need to make
      var batches = Math.ceil((counter.innerText.substring(0, counter.innerText.indexOf(" ")) - 100) / 1000);
      var listXHR = []
      for (i = 1; i < batches; i++) {
        listXHR[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
        listXHR[i].onreadystatechange = function(x) {
          if (x.target.readyState == 4 && x.target.status == 200) {
            var data = document.getElementById("tbody");
            data.innerHTML += x.target.responseText;
          }
        };
        listXHR[i].open('GET', path + '?cid=' + cid + "&title=" + title + "&batch=" + i, true);
        listXHR[i].send();
      }
    }
  };


  xhr.open('GET', path + '?cid=' + cid + "&title=" + title + "&batch=0", true);
  xhr.send();
};
```